# TMDB Api: how to assign genre number id to its own genre name with React?

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm using the TMDB api and they have each movie's genres displayed as number ids.
How do i "translate" those numbers into their own name strings?

the array with the id and names looks like this:

```
    {
      id: 18,
      name: "drama",
    },
   {
      id: 12,
      name: "adventure",
    },
   {
      id: 53,
      name: "horror",
    },
```

With vanilla js i would change it through innerText probably but i'm out of ideas with react, also cause i just started learning it.

my movie card component looks like this:

```
const ResultUI = ({ film }) => {  
  return (
    <div className="single_result_container">
      <img
        src={"https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w1280/" + film.poster_path}
      ></img>
      <div className="bio">
        <p className="title">{film.title || film.name}</p>
        <p>{film.overview}</p>
        <p>{film.vote_average}</p>
        <p>{film.genre_ids}</p> // <---this one needs to change
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ResultUI;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could translate JSON argument on ResultUI call or inside it.
Create funciont that will tranclate JSON fields, in example:

```
  const film = ....; 
for(let id in film.genre_ids}film.genre_ids[id]=`Your id`;
    
    
    <ResultUI film={film} />
```

*or*

```
const ResultUI = ({ film }) => {  
for(let id in film.genre_ids}film.genre_ids[id]=`Your id`;
 return (
    <div className="single_result_container">
      <img
        src={"https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w1280/" + film.poster_path}
      ></img>
      <div className="bio">
        <p className="title">{film.title || film.name}</p>
        <p>{film.overview}</p>
        <p>{film.vote_average}</p>
        <p>{film.genre_ids}</p> // <---this one needs to change
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ResultUI;
```